# What is predictive Horizon?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, prediction

I understand the basics of what predictive Horizon means. When we predict in future, we set up a time window. In other words, it is used to determine how far ahead the model predicts the future.

Although, I have still not understood this concept in depth and I would really appreciate if someone can explain me this concept.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you calculate a forecast using data generated before timestamp $t_1$ to forecast for a future timestamp $t_2$

Then your predictive horizon would be $t_2 - t_1$

Example: You use data up to `2021-01-01 12:00:00` to calculate a forecast for `2021-01-01 12:30:00`. Then your predictive horizon would be **30 minutes**.